# remove password prompt openvpn ubuntu client

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to save the username, and password of my openvpn client in *.secret.txt*, and I'm receiving errors when attempting to connect, or the password is requested, instead of being read from *.secret.txt*.

Here is my config file:

```
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_4EBX2EpXPZasiTv1 name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
auth-user-pass //root/.secret.txt
```

When attempting to connect, I'm still being prompted for a password:

```
Wed Aug  8 07:44:22 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul  3 2017
Wed Aug  8 07:44:22 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Enter Private Key Password:
```

Answer (score 5):

"Enter Private Key Password" suggests you may be barking up the wrong tree.

It sounds like you are authenticating based on PKI and your private key is encrypted and requires a password to use (an entirely local process).

`auth-user-pass`, on the other hand, is for authenticating to the VPN server with username and password, which is unrelated.

One option of dealing with your actual problem is to store your private key in the plain, so that no password is necessary to use it.

This can be done using `openssl rsa`, something like:

```
openssl rsa -in file1.key -out file2.key
```

And then instead using the new file in your openvpn config.

Comment: I've logged into the VPN server, and created a new RSA key.

How do I login using OpenVPN, using the new key file?

Comment: @IanArman Just to clarify, what I described did not involve the VPN server at all.

Comment: my ovpn file contains the connection information, certificate and private key (located on the openvpn client)

I searched the ubuntu client `find / -name '*.key' -print` and did not find any `.key` files.

However, on the VPN server I was able to create a `file2.key` from the keys which were created from the VPN server.

The new `file2.key` is located on the (ubuntu client).

How is the file used for connection?

Am I required to append a new (`file2.ovpn`)?

Comment: @IanArman If you have inlined the key data in your openvpn config file, then why not just take the key data from your config file and temporarily dump that in a file of its own, complete the steps and then take the resulting file and replace the inlined key data in your config file?

Comment: Can you recommend a doc?

I'm not too sure how to create the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the password for the key to the certificate in a file with this option:

```
--askpass [file]
       Get certificate password from console or file before we daemonize.
```

Comment: This actually works for me. I created two files: (1) `user_pass.txt` with username and password separated with `\n` (on Linux); (2) `private_key.txt` with the private key. Then I added `auth-user-pass /path/user_pass.txt` to the OVPN file and run `sudo openvpn --config ~/config.ovpn --askpass private_key.txt`. And it connects automatically. @IanArman did this work for you? I use OpenVPN 2.4.11 on Fedora 32 installed via `dnf` if that matters.